# Get only the most recent records from a table

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

Trying to query a database in Athena; the info's recorded in big batches by snapshot date, so one 'node' will have multiple duplicate entries - e.g.

| node | realm | snapshot_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NODEA | NA | 02/21/2022 |
| NODEA | NA | 06/30/2023 |
| NODEA | NA | 08/25/2023 |
| NODEB | NA | 03/13/2021 |
| NODEB | NA | 07/12/2022 |
| NODEB | NA | 09/23/2023 |
| NODEC | NA | 08/25/2023 |
| NODEC | NA | 09/05/2023 |

I only want the most recent entry for each unique node - e.g.

| node | realm | snapshot_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NODEA | NA | 08/25/2023 |
| NODEB | NA | 09/23/2023 |
| NODEC | NA | 09/05/2023 |

Currently trying to use a subquery and MAX() on snapshot_date, and using an inner join:

```
SELECT nodetable.*

FROM
    (SELECT
    node
    , MAX(snapshot_date) AS snapshot_date
    FROM
    nodetable
    GROUP BY
    node) AS latest_snapshot
INNER JOIN
    nodetable
ON
    nodetable.node = latest_snapshot.node AND 
    nodetable.snapshot_date = latest_snapshot.snapshot_date
    
WHERE
    realm = 'NA'
    AND is_node_enabled = 'true'
    AND node_country= 'United States'
```

But it's only returning data from the highest date in the dataset - so basically, it'll now only give me results from the most recent 9/23/23 snapshot, instead of the most recent snapshot of the node specifically.

Comment: Your query appears correct for what you are asking; except that the subquery that gets the MAX is referring to a 'table', instead of 'nodetable'. What is in 'table'?

Comment: typo on my part - subquery's pulling from nodetable too.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this approach**

```
SELECT nodetable.*
FROM nodetable
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        node,
        MAX(snapshot_date) AS snapshot_date
    FROM table
    GROUP BY node
) AS latest_snapshot
ON nodetable.node = latest_snapshot.node AND
nodetable.snapshot_date = latest_snapshot.snapshot_date
WHERE realm = 'NA'
AND is_node_enabled = 'true'
AND node_country = 'United States'
```

This query will return all rows from the nodetable table, even if there is no matching row in the latest_snapshot table. This means that the query will return data from the most recent snapshot of the node, even if that snapshot is older than the most recent snapshot in the dataset.

Note that the LEFT JOIN will also return rows from the nodetable table where there is no matching row in the latest_snapshot table. This means that you may need to add an additional filter to your WHERE clause to exclude these rows, depending on your specific needs.

Comment: Thank you - tried this, but unfortunately this just seems to return the raw data with all the snapshot duplicates included - in which case it might just be easier to pull the entire dataset and filter out the dupes in excel :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use relatively standard approach with window functions, particularly `row_number`:

```
-- sample data
WITH dataset (node, realm, snapshot_date) AS (
    values ('NODEA',    'NA',   '02/21/2022'),
        ('NODEA',   'NA',   '06/30/2023'),
        ('NODEA',   'NA',   '08/25/2023'),
        ('NODEB',   'NA',   '03/13/2021'),
        ('NODEB',   'NA',   '07/12/2022'),
        ('NODEB',   'NA',   '09/23/2023'),
        ('NODEC',   'NA',   '08/25/2023'),
        ('NODEC',   'NA',   '09/05/2023')
)

SELECT node, realm, snapshot_date
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        -- assign row numbers per node in reverse order date
        row_number() over (partition by node order by date_parse(snapshot_date, '%m/%d/%Y') desc ) rn
    FROM dataset
)
where rn = 1 -- take "latest"
;
```

Output:

| node | realm | snapshot_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NODEA | NA | 08/25/2023 |
| NODEC | NA | 09/05/2023 |
| NODEB | NA | 09/23/2023 |